# Boostrap/CSS Responsive vertically centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have 3 `<a>` with the `btn` bootstrap class on it.

I found how to center those horizontally and vertically with the above code

**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-centered ">
    <div class="vertically-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#">Prepare</a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px;">Handover</a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#">Tuto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .btn-lg{
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right:10px;
    }

    .row-centered {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        font: 0/0 a;
    }

    .row-centered:before {
        content: ' ';
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .vertically-centered {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-centered {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
```

It works as expected when the screen is wide enough
[image]

But it is failing when the screen is smaller (width) than 830px
[image]

**EDIT**

I change the HTML and CSS

**HTML MODIFIED**

```
<div class="row row-centered ">
    <div class="vertically-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary" href="#">Prepare</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary" href="#">Handover</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary" href="#">Tuto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS MODIFIED**

```
.btn-lg{
            padding-top:30px;
            padding-bottom:30px;
            width:100%;
        }

    .row-centered {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        font: 0/0 a;
    }

    .row-centered:before {
        content: ' ';
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .vertically-centered {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-centered {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
```

Now my problem is that I button are aligned above each other (which is nice) but they are going under my `nav-background`

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's happening due to the manually specified margins. You could possibly replace them with `col-md-push-#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the nav was a custome class instead of the `navbar` class from boostrap

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin on the middle button to a percentage value:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#" style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%;">Handover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you use a margin before and after the middle link. What I try to do is solve it with empty columns

```
<div class="row row-centered ">
    <div class="vertically-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#">Prepare</a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" href="#"></a> 
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#">Handover</a>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1" href="#"></a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-primary col-centered col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" href="#">Tuto</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```